# interpreting this assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to interpret the following IA32 assembler code and write a function in C that will have an equivalent effect.

Let's say that parameters `a`, `b` and `c` are stored at memory locations with offsets `8`, `12` and `16` relative to the address in register `%ebp`, and that an appropriate function prototype in C would be `equivFunction(int a, int b, int c);`

```
movl 12(%ebp), %edx // store b into %edx
subl 16(%ebp), %edx // %edx = b - c
movl %edx, %eax     // store b - c into %eax
sall $31, %eax      // multiply (b-c) * 2^31
sarl $31, %eax      // divide ((b-c)*2^31)) / 2^31
imull 8(%ebp), %edx // multiply a * (b - c) into %edx
xorl %edx, %eax     // exclusive or? %edx or %eax ?  what is going on here?
```

First, did I interpret the assembly correctly?  If so, how would I go about translating this into C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sall`/`sarl` combo has the effect of setting all bits of eax to the value of the zeroth bit. First, `sal` moves the 0th bit to the 31st position, making it a sign bit. Then `sar` moves it back, filling the rest of the register with its copy. Don't think of it as division/multiplication - think of it as bitwise shift, which "s" actually stands for.

So eax is 0xffffffff (-1) if b-c is odd, 0 if even. So the `imull` command places into edx either a negative of a, or zero. The final `xor`, then, either inverts the all bits of `a` (that's what `xor` with one does) or leaves the zero value be.

This whole snippet has an air of artificiality. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The shifts manipulate the sign bit directly, rather than multiplying/dividing, so the code is roughly

```
int eqivFunction(int a, int b, int c) {
    int t1 = b - c;
    unsigned t2 = t1 < 0 ? ~0U : 0;
    return (a * t1) ^ t2;
}
```

Alternately:

```
int eqivFunction(int a, int b, int c) {
    int t1 = b - c;
    int t2 = a * t1;
    if (t1 < 0) t2 = -t2 - 1;
    return t2;
}
```

Of course, the C code has undefined behavior on integer overflow, while the assembly code is well-defined, so the C code might not do the same thing in all cases (particularly if you compile it on a different architecture)